# Что делает оператор "^" в Python?

Tags: python, синтаксис, операторы

Как можно узнать о назначении оператора "^"?

Comment: Добрый день.  [tag:объекты] — довольно-таки неинформативная и обобщенная метка, я бы не рекомендовал ставить её на вопросы. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/52132

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Как можно узнать о назначении оператора "^"?

`help('^')` в Питоне говорит, что это ["bitwise XOR (exclusive OR)" оператор](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1746613/4279). `help()` помогает найти смысл символов, которые сложно в поисковике искать или помогает узнать ключевые слова, по которым можно дальнейший поиск производить (полезно также просматривать related topics, найденные `help()` вызовом).

`help()` работает не только для операторов, например, `help('...')`, `help('symbols')`, `help('json')`, `help(help)`…

Answer (score 11):

Это оператор XOR. Как можно узнать - набрать в гугле фразу "%langname% operators".

Comment: А это логический или побитовый оператор?)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev hex(0xAA ^ 0x55) -> 0xFF так что как минимум битовый.

Answer (score 9):

Это побитовый оператор Исключающее ИЛИ или XOR. [Ссылка на документацию.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)