# Не правильно срабатывают два оператора

Tags: python

```
OPERATORS = {'+': (1, lambda x, y: x + y), '-': (1, lambda x, y: x - y),
         '*': (2, lambda x, y: x * y), '/': (2, lambda x, y: x / y),
         'x': (2, lambda x, y: x * y),'^': (2, lambda x, y: x ** y)}
```

два последних оператора

```
def eval_(formula):
    def parse(formula_string):
    number = ''
    for s in formula_string:
        if s in '1234567890.':
            number += s
        elif number:
            yield float(number)
            number = ''
        if s in OPERATORS or s in "()":
            yield s
    if number:
        yield float(number)

   def shunting_yard(parsed_formula):
    stack = []
    for token in parsed_formula:
        if token in OPERATORS:
            while stack and stack[-1] != "(" and OPERATORS[token][0] <= OPERATORS[stack[-1]][0]:
                yield stack.pop()
            stack.append(token)
        elif token == ")":
            while stack:
                x = stack.pop()
                if x == "(":
                    break
                yield x
        elif token == "(":
            stack.append(token)
        else:
            yield token
    while stack:
        yield stack.pop()

   def calc(polish):
    stack = []
    for token in polish:
        if token in OPERATORS:
            y, x = stack.pop(), stack.pop()
            stack.append(OPERATORS[token][1](x, y))
        else:
            stack.append(token)
    return stack[0]

return calc(shunting_yard(parse(formula)))
```

в словарике операторы 5 шт при использовании в формулах работают отлично, '**', '+', '/', '-', '*'
например

print(eval("2**4")) - 16

остальные работают странно или совсем не работают '^' - '^': (2, lambda x, y: x ** y)

print(eval("2^4")) - 6 ?

print(eval("2x4"))  - не работает совсем

```
    if s in OPERATORS or s in "()":
        yield s
```

проблема я думаю в этом месте, но не понимаю почему работает с 4 символами и не хочет с остальными.

парсер собственно отсюда, просто попробовал чутка расширить функционал

https://habrahabr.ru/post/273253/

Comment: Приведите примеры, в которых неправильно работает и как должно быть.

Comment: print(eval("2**4")) - 16 ок, print(eval("2^4")) - 6 не ок,  print(eval("2x4")) совсем не работает, 1й работает при добавленном в словарик операторы ('    '**': (2, lambda x, y: x ** y))

Comment: гм курсив испортил выше print(eval("2**4")) - 16

Comment: Внизу вопроса есть "править", воспользуйтесь этим и обновите вопрос. Так будет проще разобраться с проблемой

Comment: Я немножко не понял - почему функция называется `eval_`, а вызываете вы `eval`?

Comment: @djt111, назовите функцию как-нибудь совсем по-другому, чтобы не путать со встроенной функцией `eval`. Для встроенной `eval` оператор `^` - это XOR, т.е. `2 ^ 4 = 0b0010 ^ 0b0100 = 0b0110 = 6`. Естественно, встроенная `eval` ничего не знает о вашем операторе `x`.

Comment: чорд, я не знал что есть встроенная =))) и не мог понять почему работает так, а при 1м вводе просто ideшка подсказала название =)

Comment: в тему: [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371436/4279)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Что делает оператор “^” в Python?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/477581/23044)