# Определить является ли строка квадратным уравнением

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

Добрый день! Требуется определить тип уравнения. Пока что, хватит определения, является ли уравнение квадратным или нет. В распоряжении есть sympy и numpy(предпочтительнее первый). Есть идеи?

Уравнение, которое будет входить на эту проверку, уже будет приведено к стандартному виду. Квадратным уравнением стоит считать только уравнение вида ax^2+bx+c

Используется Python 3.5

Comment: В какой форме уравнение задано? Является ли `(x**2 - x**2)` уравнение квадратным?

Comment: Нет, не является. Квадратным уравнением стоит считать только уравнение вида a*x^2+b*x+c

Comment: Я ясно вижу вторую степень. Почему не является? (потому что вы думаете, что можно упростить?) А вот это является: `(e**(i*pi) + 1)*x**2`?

Comment: Уравнение, которое будет входить на эту проверку, уже будет приведено к стандартному виду. Думаю, нет смысла заморачиваться с такими, более сложными уравнениями

Comment: что значит "стандартный вид" (как это в Питоне выглядит: как sympy объект, с одной переменной, а остальные константы? Как строка (`type(o) == str`), в которой только `x` считается переменным? [Знак `^` в Питоне означает XOR](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/477581/23044)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr, standard_transformations,implicit_multiplication_application, convert_xor
>>> transformations = standard_transformations +   (implicit_multiplication_application, convert_xor)
>>> is_quadratic = lambda s: parse_expr(s, transformations=transformations).as_poly().degree() == 2
>>> is_quadratic("ax^2+bx+c")
True
>>> is_quadratic("bx+c")
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот решение с помощью регулярных выражений. Не работает, если перед `x` коэффициент не в виде одного вещественного числа из цифр (запятой или точки для дробей). Наверняка можно выражение как-то упростить.

```
import re
equations = [
    '56.6x**2 -  9,76543',
    '566x^2 -2.0*x + 9,76543',
    '33x - 9',
    '7',
    '66x^4',
    '4.885x**2- 3*x',
    '7x+x^2',
    '2x**2-3,90.9x',
    '55*x**2']
for eq in equations:
    equation = eq.replace(' ', '')
    result = re.match(r'(([1-9]+([,\.]\d+)?|0\.\d+)\*?)?x(\*\*|\^)2([\+-](\d+([,\.]\d+)?\*?)?x)?([\+-]\d+([,\.]\d+)?)?'
             , equation)
    if result and len(result.group(0)) == len(equation):
        print('Это квадратное уравнение: ' + result.group(0))
    else:
        print('Это не квадратное уравнение!!! ' + eq)
```

Вывод:

```
Это квадратное уравнение: 56.6x**2-9,76543
Это квадратное уравнение: 566x^2-2.0*x+9,76543
Это не квадратное уравнение!!! 33x - 9
Это не квадратное уравнение!!! 7
Это не квадратное уравнение!!! 66x^4
Это квадратное уравнение: 4.885x**2-3*x
Это не квадратное уравнение!!! 7x+x^2
Это не квадратное уравнение!!! 2x**2-3,90.9x
Это квадратное уравнение: 55*x**2
```