# Вставить недостающие знаки умножения в выражение

Tags: python, python-3.5, sympy

Привет всем. Уже несколько дней ломаю голову. Пользователь вводит какое-то выражение, например, 2x+3y=0. Необходимо расставить тут знаки умножение, чтобы дальше с ним можно было работать при помощи sympy

Comment: если ставить tag `python` - то вероятность того что ваш вопрос будет замечен сильно повышается. Многие фильтруют вопросы по тегам и указывать в фильтрах все комбинации `python-3.x`, `python-2.x`, `python-3.5` и т.д. не будут - просто укажут `python`. PS я сейчас случайно набрел на этот вопрос...

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Определить является ли строка квадратным уравнением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637305/23044)

Answer (score 2):

```
import sympy

from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import standard_transformations,implicit_multiplication_application

transformations = (standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,))


a = parse_expr('2x + 3y', transformations=transformations)
```

[Сcылка на документацию](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/parsing.html)

Результат:

```
In [5]: print(a)
2*x + 3*y
```