# упрощение многочлена python

Tags: python, математика

Входные данные:`(x+1)(y+1)+(x+1)y+xy`
Нужно найти решение которое "откроет" скобки и посчитает результат чтобы на выходе получить: `xy + x + y + 1 + xy + y + xy`

Comment: Входные данные это что ли строка `"(x+1)(y+1)+(x+1)y+xy"`?

Comment: @gil9red да ...

Comment: `xy` - это переменная или `x*y`?

Comment: [Похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648428/%d0%92%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: @MaxU x*y......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот способ использующий [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org), но также поддерживающий [неявное умножение](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/parsing.html#sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.implicit_multiplication):

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import (parse_expr, standard_transformations, implicit_multiplication_application)
from sympy import *
input_str = "(x+1)(y+1)+(x+1)y+xy"
transformations = standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,)
print(expand(parse_expr(input_str, transformations=transformations))) # 3*x*y + x + 2*y + 1
```

Comment: эта библиотека что-то с чем то :)

Comment: Мне вот интересно стало, что это библиотека не может сделать...

Comment: @AndrioSkur вычислить такое выражение: `parse_expr("2+f(2)", evaluate=False)` и не упасть с ошибкой