# Что это за знак | а скорее что он делает в python 3.

Tags: python, python-3.x

Что это за знак | а скорее что он делает в python 3.

Comment: попробуйте `help('|')` в REPL. Связанный вопрос: [Что делает оператор "^" в Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/477581/23044)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как и во многих других языках, это оператор ["побитовое ИЛИ"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%C2%AB%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%98%C2%BB_(OR)):

```
print (hex(0x55 | 0xAA))
```

выдаст 0xFF