# Код выдаёт неправильный ответ. Задача: Определите тип треугольника (остроугольный, тупоугольный, прямоугольный) с данными сторонами

Tags: python

**Формат входных данных**

*Даны три натуральных числа – стороны треугольника. Каждое число вводится с новой строки.*

**Формат выходных данных:**

*Необходимо вывести одно из слов:

right для прямоугольного треугольника,

acute для остроугольного треугольника,

obtuse для тупоугольного треугольника,

impossible, если треугольника с такими сторонами не существует.*

Я запускаю вот такой код:

```
x=int(input())
y=int(input())
z=int(input())
c = max(x,y,z)
if c==x:
    a, b =  y, z
elif c==y:
    a,b=x,z
else:
    a, b = x, y

if c>=a+b:
    print('impossible')
else:
    if c^2==(a^2+b^2):
        print('right')
    elif c^2<(a^2+b^2):
        print('acute')
    else:
        print('obtuse')
```

Для входных чисел
8
10
6

Выдаётся результат: "obtuse", хотя правильно "right". Скажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что делает оператор "^" в Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477581/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b2-python)

Comment: Оператор `^` не имеет никакого отношения к возведению в степень в питоне и в массе других языков, это побитовая операция XOR (исключающее ИЛИ).  Возведение в степень в питоне выполняется при помощи оператора `**`, для квадрата можно было бы просто записать `if c * c == a * a + b * b:`

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в вашем текущем коде связана с использованием оператора побитового исключающего ИЛИ ^ вместо оператора возведения в квадрат **

Вот исправленный вариант вашего кода, где я заменил ^ на ** для возведения чисел в квадрат:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
c = max(x, y, z)

if c == x:
    a, b = y, z
elif c == y:
    a, b = x, z
else:
    a, b = x, y

if c >= a + b:
    print('impossible')
else:
    if c ** 2 == (a ** 2 + b ** 2):
        print('right')
    elif c ** 2 < (a ** 2 + b ** 2):
        print('acute')
    else:
        print('obtuse')
```

Comment: У вас код не приложен.

Comment: `a, b, c = sorted((x, y, z))`.

Comment: А это "if c == x:" зачем? Достаточно определить только самую длинную сторону.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy лишнее. "c = max" достаточно.

Comment: @rotabor, если не менять сравнения в конце, то кроме `c` нужно выделить `a` и `b`. `sorted` хотя и делает лишнюю работу, зато размещает все значения по своим местам в один оператор.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy В конце чего? Даже если не вдаваться в теорию, а посмотреть на код, начиная с "if c >= a + b:", то обмен местами a и b ничего не меняет. По крайней мере, для этого кода сортировать две короткие стороны не нужно. И по теории тоже не нужно.

Comment: @c >= a + b, в операторе `if c >= a + b` вам нужны и `c` и `a` и `b`. Если просто выделить `c = max(...)`, то понадобятся условные операторы для заполнения `a` и `b`. Я предложил `sorted` чтобы избавиться от блока кода со строки `if c == x:`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ну да, это я провтыкал

Comment: @rotabor, но есть хулиганский способ поменять формулы. Все сравнения можно переписать в терминах `c`, `x`, `y`, `z` без выделения в отдельные переменные двух меньших значений. Но это уже из разряда ненормального программирования.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy нашёл вариант без хулиганства

Comment: @rotabor, добавил ответ. В конце вариант без сортировки и выделения `a` и `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Оператор `^` в Питоне - это [XOR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%C2%AB%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%C2%BB). Для возведения в степень используется оператор `**`. Ниже ваша программа с минимальными исправлениями:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
c = max(x, y, z)

if c == x:
    a, b = y, z
elif c == y:
    a, b = x, z
else:
    a, b = x, y

if c >= a + b:
    print('impossible')
else:
    if c ** 2 == a ** 2 + b ** 2:
        print('right')
    elif c ** 2 < a ** 2 + b ** 2:
        print('acute')
    else:
        print('obtuse')
```

Её можно переписать проще:

```
a, b, c = sorted(int(input()) for _ in range(3))

if c >= a + b:
    print('impossible')
else:
    residual = c ** 2 - a ** 2 - b ** 2
    if residual == 0:
        print('right')
    elif residual < 0:
        print('acute')
    else:
        print('obtuse')
```

И ещё есть хулиганский способ без сортировки:

```
sides = [int(input()) for _ in range(3)]
c = max(sides)

if 2 * c >= sum(sides):
    print('impossible')
else:
    residual = 2 * c ** 2 - sum(v ** 2 for v in sides)
    if residual == 0:
        print('right')
    elif residual < 0:
        print('acute')
    else:
        print('obtuse')
```

Comment: Почему же хулиганский? Очень даже хороший, на 5.

Comment: @rotabor, хулиганский потому что неравенство треугольника и теорема косинусов используются но не видны явно. Кода сделан неочевидным чтобы упростить обработку входных данные.